# Ability to filter a store remotely and locally

Tags: extjs, extjs-stores, extjs7

I am using Ext JS 7.1 Modern, and I want to know if there is a way to filter a store also **locally** which has `remoteFilter: true`.

I have tried to explain my case with a [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32vc) and also attached the code below.

The example contains a store that simulates remote filtering to a server by using dynamic data defined in `names.json` and setting `remoteFilter` and `filters` config.

```
    remoteFilter: true,
    filters: {
        property: 'id',
        value: 1
    }
```

After the data is retrieved, suppose the user wants to filter the retrieved data locally by typing into the 'search' field. Now, I want to filter the store locally, but since `remoteFilter` is set to `true`, the filter that I set sends a request to the server instead of doing local filtering.

Is there a straightforward way to realize this use-case? It feels like a very common use-case that everybody would need, so I wanted to be sure that I am not missing something.

app.js

```
Ext.define('App.store.TestStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.teststore',

    fields: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName'],

    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'names.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    },

    remoteFilter: true,
    filters: {
        property: 'id',
        value: 1
    }
});

Ext.define('App.controller.TestController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.testcontroller',

    doSearch: function(field) {
        var list = this.lookup('list'),
            store = list.getStore(),
            value = field.getValue();

        var filters = store.getFilters();
        if (Ext.isEmpty(value))
            filters.remove('firstName')
        else {
            filters.add(new Ext.util.Filter({
                property: 'firstName',
                value: value,
                operator: 'in'
            }))
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('App.dataview.TestList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'testlist',

    store: {
        type: 'teststore'
    },
    itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{id} <b>{firstName} {lastName}</b></div>'
});

Ext.define('App.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    controller: 'testcontroller',
    fullscreen: true,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'searchfield',
        ui: 'solo',
        placeholder: 'Search names',
        listeners: {
            buffer: 500,
            change: 'doSearch'
        }
    }, {
        reference: 'list',
        xtype: 'testlist'
    }]

})

Ext.application({
    name: 'App',

    mainView: 'App.MainView',

    launch: function () {

    }
});
```

names.json

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Peter',
    lastName: 'Venkman'
}, {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Raymond',
    lastName: 'Stantz'
}, {
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Egon',
    lastName: 'Spengler'
}, {
    id: 4,
    firstName: 'Winston',
    lastName: 'Zeddemore'
}]

var results = data.filter(function(record) {
    if (params.filter) {
        return record.id > params.filter[0].value
    }
})

return {
    "success": true,
    "data": results
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the chained store functionality. Filter your main store remotely, then create a chained store based off the main store to apply extra local filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use the chained store functionality. Filter your main store remotely, then create a chained store based off the main store to apply extra local filters.

Evan is right. In early version Extjs we can loaded `remoteFilter: true`, and local filtered data with help method `filterBy`. Cleared filter local we can call `clearFilter` method with argument `true`.

But in latest version that functional was removed.

**onFilterEndUpdate** method

```
 if (me.getRemoteFilter()) {

            me.getFilters().each(function(filter) {
                if (filter.getInitialConfig().filterFn) {
                    Ext.raise('Unable to use a filtering function in conjunction with ' + 'remote filtering.');
                }
            });

          ....
        }
```

How to use `chainedstore` you can see in my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32vq)